# Fall Guys on Low Spec

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

I'm trying to get fall guys to run on Intel HD Graphics 620, Intel i7-7500u, 8GB ram. When I try to run fall guys I get a grey screen then crash. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

Your system doesn't meet the [minimum requirements](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1097150/Fall_Guys_Ultimate_Knockout/), so it's likely not going to work until you get yourself a better graphics card.

> MINIMUM:
>
> - Requires a 64-bit processor and operating system
> - OS: Windows 10 64bit only
> - Processor: Intel Core i5 or AMD equivalent
> - Memory: 8 GB RAM
> - Graphics: NVIDIA GTX 660 or AMD Radeon HD 7950
> - Network: Broadband Internet connection
> - Storage: 2 GB available space
> - Additional Notes: Gamepad Recommended

Comment: Yes. I understand. Search on YouTube and many people have been able to run it. However even if i don't meet them, the main menu should load.

Comment: What error did you get? Any logs?

Comment: It just crashes. Cursor changes, Grey screen appears, crash.

Comment: No...if an app doesn't meet minimum specs, there's no guarantee what happens to it when you attempt to load.  I suppose you could take this up with the company yourself; I'm only the messenger on this.

Comment: Did you search on youtube? I told you that people have done it. I don't care if it dosen't work, its just that other people have done it and i don't have a better pc and there's nothing graphics intensive about a main menu

Comment: There might be a 'equipement check' right when it boots. If it detects your PC will not be able to run the game in at least a decent matter, it just crashes. Also, if you've seen videos on youtube of people without the specs running it, maybe the check has been patched in, maybe they do some weird voodoo to bypass it. Either way, if you do not meet the requirements I would tell you to not play the game. The experience will only be subpar. My 12 year old pc (that was not a bomb to start with) can run this... if you can't its more than time to invest in a new PC mate.

Comment: Just cause a pc doesn't meet the requirements doesn't mean it is incapable of playing the game.  This question does *not* have answers in the question listed, because he didn't ask how to find out if his pc meets requirements, he asked why his pc is crashing
!